# Problem running pyspark spark-submit in a virtualenv?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Appear to be having issues running a pyspark script in a virtualenv. Have a fairly simple script

```py
import findspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from os import environ


environ["HADOOP_CONF_DIR"] = "/etc/hadoop/3.1.0.0-78/0"

findspark.init("/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client")

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "HW01.co.local:8050")
conf.setAppName('spark-yarn-demo001')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


def inside(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return x*x + y*y < 1

NUM_SAMPLES=1000
count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)) \
             .filter(inside).count()

print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

(I know the `spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager` port is usually 8032, but on my HDP 3.1 cluster the default configs are at 8050) and trying to run via spark-submit.

```sh
(spark_demo_venv) [hdfs@HW04 tmp]$ which python
~/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python
(spark_demo_venv) [hdfs@HW04 tmp]$ /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit /home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_001.py
```

Seeing errors like...

```sh
...
19/08/27 14:31:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on HW03.ucera.local:35043 (size: 4.0 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
19/08/27 14:31:58 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, HW03.ucera.local, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:186)
...
```

Yet looking at that path...

```sh
[root@HW04 tmp]# ls -lh /home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 hdfs hadoop 7 Aug 27 14:14 /home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python -> python2
[root@HW04 tmp]# ls -lh /home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 hdfs hadoop 7.1K Aug 27 14:14 /home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python2
```

it looks like it should be publicly accessible.
The fact that the virtualenv python binary is what spark appears to have trouble finding makes me think that there is something wrong with trying to run pyspark in a virtualenv (can't test without virtualenv, since don't have permissions to pip install on this cluster node). Any other debugging suggestions or fixes for figuring this out?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/hdfs/tmp/spark_demo_venv/bin/python` when you run `ls -l` on it?

Comment: @LiamClarke Updated post with a bit more info, but looking at `ls -l ...` the location should be publicly accessible.